# Want to open new tab while using Resolve.url in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to open new tab while using Resolve.url in asp.net c#.

```
 previewlink.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/admin/Preview_paper.aspx");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the hyperlink's `Target` property to "_blank":

`Target = "_blank"`

Though it may go without saying, if the user's browser settings are such that they use new windows instead of tabs, this will open it in a new window, but I'm guessing that's not an issue.

EDIT: here's some sample code

```
previewlink.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/admin/Preview_paper.aspx");
previewlink.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: `ResolveUrl` just reformats the relative URL you provide with reference to the web page currently being used.  The `Target` is a completely separately modifier for the link which tells the browser what window it should open to (itself, another named window, or a new window) and is not affected by the `NavigateUrl`. Just like setting its CssClass or Style attributes do not affect the link URL.

Answer (score 2):

The target attribute of a hyperlink must be set wil `"_blank"` in order to open the target url in a new window

Please set `target = "_blank"`

**Update : on comment of OP**

```
The target is a property as you can see below of the Hyperlink 
   <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
                  ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
                  NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
                  Text="Microsoft Official Site"
                  Target="_blank"
                  runat="server"/>
```